# Why are there no apps for taking spherical panoramas on a smartphone?

Tags: mobile, photography

I was just searching for a quick way to create a 360 by 180 degree spherical panorama. For testing purposes i thought, there must be an mobile app for that. After 15 minutes of googling I had to realize that there is no good or at least popular app for that. Viewers for such images there were a few, but not to capture and create them.

I started looking into software on a computer, and even here theee are just a few tools that can do the desired task.

But why are there no apps for that? Is it to complex to solve on a phone?